# Overlapping textures with nodes?

Tags: node-editor, transparency

[image: mix shader]

I am working on a shader setup where a transparent yellow texture should go under a black text texture. I tried using a mix shader to put one on top of the other but I get something like above, where you get a 50/50 mix of the two. I was hoping to get 100/100 of both textures on the object, is there any way to do this? I'm not sure if a mix shader is the right node to use for this.

Node setup:

[image: node setup]

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of your node setup, there's currently not enough information to be able to help you. Also what render engine are you using, Cycles, Blender Internal, GLSL/Game Engine?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: @cegaton Thanks I think that solves it. : )